# Fb request dialog returns nil incorrectly - IOS Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-requests

Thanks for reading!

I'm trying to create a Facebook request to enable the user to invite his friends to the app.

```
 NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

        [FBWebDialogs
         presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
         message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
         title:@"Test"
         parameters:params
         handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                 NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
             } else {
                 if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                     // User clicked the "x" icon
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // Handle the send request callback
                     NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                     if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                         // User clicked the Cancel button
                         NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                     } else {
                         // User clicked the Send button
                         NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                         NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }];
```

}

This is pretty much a clean copy of the Facebook docs code. And it works up to a point
The user can choose the friends and the request goes away and gets received by the friends and it shows up as a notification - everything fine so far.

The problem is that when I try to get the response from the "handler" the `resultURL` is nil and does not contain anything. And after that I get the log message "User canceled request".

Why don't I get anything back? The main reason that I need this is that I need to know which friends the request was sent to.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're passing an nil empty session to `presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession`

Use `FBSession.activeSession` instead and check you have enough permissions to run the request (although if not, you would be getting another different error)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not having a session opened..please try to use this to open the session.

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                               allowLoginUI:YES
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                 FBSessionState state,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
     }];
    }
```